# SVD square and invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, svd

Let $A=U \Sigma V^T$ be a $n \times n$ square and invertible matrix. Matrices $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix.

I've read in some lecture notes that if matrix $A$ is square and invertible then $U$, $V$, and $\Sigma$ are also square matrices. 
How is this statement possible?

Isn't it possible that $U$ and $V$ are $n \times m$ and $\Sigma$ is $m \times m$ where $n > m$? In this case, we can only say $U^TU=I$ and $V^TV=I$.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It's called "economy SVD" and it's used when you have zero singular values. However, if $A$ is invertible, there won't be any zero singular values. You must drop the invertibility. Or, alternatively, your "economy SVD" will not be the SVD of $A$ but rather an approximation of lower rank.

Comment: Could you give me more details about "economy SVD"?

Comment: Economy SVD — used to avoid wasteful multiplication of zero singular values and rank-$1$ matrices of the form ${\rm u}_i {\rm v}_i^\top$. Recall that $$\mathrm A = \mathrm U \Sigma \mathrm V^{\top} = \sigma_1 \mathrm u_1 \mathrm v_1^{\top} + \sigma_2 \mathrm u_2 \mathrm v_2^{\top} + \cdots + \sigma_n \mathrm u_n \mathrm v_n^{\top}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to make the matrices smaller, yes. But then $U\Sigma V^T$ wouldn't be the SVD of $A$.

If $A$ is singular, then some of the diagonal entries of $\Sigma$ are zero, and could, in principle, be cut out, along with the corresponding columns of $U$ and $V$. But that's not the true SVD. Also, $A$ is assumed to be invertible, and a simple rank argument then shows that $U, \Sigma$ and $V$ must all be at least $n\times n$.

Comment: Could you give me more details about the simple rank argument?

Comment: @user19283043 The rank of a product is at most the rank of any factor, and the rank of a matrix is at most equal to the number of rows and at most equal to the number of columns. Together, this means that the rank of a product is at most equal to the smallest number of rows of any matrix in the product, and at most equal to the smallest number of columns of any matrix in the product. And an $n\times n$ matrix like $A$ is invertible iff the rank is $n$.

Comment: What does mean by "that's not the true SVD"?

Comment: Well, if you read what the SVD does, and how it works, $\Sigma$ has the same dimensions as $A$ does for a square $A$ (really, it has the dimensions of $A^TA$). So by necessity, $U$ and $V$ must be square. That is the SVD. No way around it. But as I noted, you could "throw out" any rows and columns that correspond to zero entries in $\Sigma$, giving you what is called "economy SVD" in the comments above. It's not really the SVD, but it's close.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the awesome explanation.

Answer (score 0):

When $A$ is a square matrix, SVD just becomes the diagonalization. In that Case $A$ can be written as $P^{-1}DP$ where $P$ is the matrix with orthonormal eigen vectors of $A$ as columns. In such a case $P^{-1} = P^{T}$. Since $A$ is a square matrix, it has $n$ eigen values, and $n$ eigen vectors. So, all the matrices on the r.h.s are square.

Comment: You can SVD non-diagonalizable square matrices. So, no, it doesn't become the diagonalization.

Comment: And $P^{-1}=P^T$ is only possible if $A$ is symmetric, as is the "$n$ eigen values, and $n$ eigen vectors" thing, even when you phrase it correctly.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out the inverse is transpose only if A is symmetric, but when you apply SVD on a square matrix, isn't it the same as diagonalization?

Comment: No, it isn't. In particular because any matrix can be SVD'd, but there are matrices which cannot be diagonalized. Also, the entries of $\Sigma$ are all non-negative.

Comment: And also, $U$ and $V^T$ aren't necessarily inverses, but when diagonalizing they are. But then the diagonal matrix can have negative entries, which isn't the case for SVD. So there is little overlap between the two.